# JQuery UI Dialog query dialog DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

The following simply loads a jquery-ui dialog from an external html file.

```
$('#showdialog').click(function(e) {
    var div = $('<div>loading...</div>');
    div.dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function() { div.load('anotherpage.html'); }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

After the DOM loads from the external html file, I'd like to interrogate it with JQuery.  For example, supposing anothorpage.html had a bunch of anchors on it, I'd like to wire up click handlers for them when it loads into the dialog.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define more then one parameter of `jQuery.load` (see http://api.jquery.com/load/) so after load is done you can do something:

```
div.load('anotherpage.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

place code which you need instead of `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using `.live()` or `.delegate()`, which will allow you to attach handlers to events on elements within the dynamically loaded content.

For example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('div.yourDynamicContainer a').live('click', function() {
        doSomething()
    })
})
```